# How to sum the multiply all numbers in a list with another numbers in another list. (Same order)

Tags: python, sum, multiplication, dot-product

I want to sum the multiply of 2 list respectively (a[0] with b[0] until a[n] with b[n]) Note: l use n because the list of a and b are free input, so, there can be much number.

If the inputed data are :

```
A = [ 12 , 0 , 3 , 7 , 2]
B = [ 1 , 2 , 5 , 4]
```

I want the sum of A*B (12*1 + 0*2 + 3*5 + 7*4 + 2*0 (since there is no more in B))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue` argument:

```
sum(x*y for x, y in zip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0))
```

**Code**:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

A = [12, 0, 3, 7, 2]
B = [1, 2, 5, 4]

print(sum(x*y for x, y in zip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0)))
# 55
```

Since `fillvalue` is 0 and that doesn't cause any change to the operation (2 * 0 = 0), you can just use `zip` as well:

```
sum(x*y for x, y in zip(A, B))
```

---

A **functional approach** is pretty pythonic (assuming `fillvalue` is still 0):

```
from operator import mul

A = [12, 0, 3, 7, 2]
B = [1, 2, 5, 4]

print(sum(map(mul, A, B)))
# 55
```

Answer (score 1):

If always happens that `len(A) >= len(B)`

```
>>> sum([A[i]*B[i] for i in range(len(B))])
55
```

else modify that to

```
sum([A[i]*B[i] for i in range(min([len(A), len(B)]))])
```

**Update**

I just noticed that `zip` is fine also with different list lengths,
so I think the best would be:

```
>>> sum([a*b for a, b in zip(A, B)])
55
```